# Как сравнивать информацию из полей структуры?

Tags: c++, структуры

Код не усложнён чрезмерно, просто я убрала ненужные для вопроса части:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct room
{
    float Squere;
};

struct home
{
    room Room;
};

int main()
{
    home HOME[5];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Space: "; cin >> HOME->Room.Squere;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

А теперь нужно как-то сравнить введённые площади (Squere) и вывести большую и меньшую. Я не знаю как это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Хоть направление в котором думать.

Уже пробовала через создание вектора, но всё равно не понимаю как именно загнать туда введённые значения.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то? Как найти максимум и минимум массива? Кстати, проверьте цикл ввода. Сейчас там 5 раз запрашивается ввод для первого элемента массива.

Comment: @EOF вопрос в том, как вывести после цикла большую и меньшую значения переменной. Ведь они задаются через структуру, в которой ещё и другие поля есть. Цикл проверила, вроде нормально работает, пока что не вижу ошибку. Но заранее спасибо за указание, если вдруг её увижу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот набросок из вашего кода.

```
home HOME[5];
float m = 1e30, M = -1e30;
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    cout << "Space: "; 
    cin >> HOME[i].Room.Squere;
    if (m > HOME[i].Room.Squere) m = HOME[i].Room.Squere;
    if (M < HOME[i].Room.Squere) M = HOME[i].Room.Squere;
}

cout << "Min: " << m << endl;
cout << "Max: " << M << endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!